# 2 views for the same ViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, view, viewcontroller

I'm making an iPhone app using Xcode 7 beta 3. The app includes several ViewControllers. For my main page, i would like to have 2 different views: 1 for Landscape, and 1 for Portrait. Can it be done using swift ? (without using Auto Layout)

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  I'd suggest trying it out and then revise your post when you have a specific problem related to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use different size classes for each orientation and design your views accordingly. Note that if you do it without autolayout though then you will have to do this for every view size combination and orientation which gets extremely tedious.

Comment: Hm.. The idea that i have more than 4 big buttons one under the other. In portrait mode, it's nice. But when i rotate it, few buttons disappear/become out of frame. I tried to lock orientation to portrait but couldn't do it. But regarding what you said, what should I put inside my classes to point whether the device is in orientation or portrait so it could change view controllers ? ( If you have a solution to lock orientations its better: i have a main page in portrait mode, and other view controllers in landscape mode ONLY )

Comment: That's exactly what size classes are. You select a size class that corresponds to a type of iOS device, instead of Any Width Any Height you would choose the one that is related to the device/orientation you're trying build for.